# A problem with Riccati's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $$ x'=-\frac {4}{t^2}-\frac 1 t x+x^2$$ knowing that $\gamma (t)=\frac 2 t $ is a particular solution.

So I make a substitution $x=\gamma (t)+\frac 1 u$
$$x=\frac 2 t +\frac 1 u$$
$$x'=\frac {-2}{t^2}-\frac {u'}{u^2}$$
After substituting into the original equation I get $$-u'=\frac 3 t u+1$$
Solving that gives me: $$u=\frac {C-t^4}{4t^3}$$
So $\frac 1 u $ should be a solution to the original equation, but it somehow isn't.

Lets plug $C=0$
$$y = \frac 1 u = -\frac 4 t $$
$$y'=\frac {4}{t^2}$$
$$\frac {4}{t^2}=-\frac {4}{t^2}-\frac {4}{t^2}+\frac {16}{t^2}$$

Can someone tell me where did I make a mistake?

Comment: "So $\frac 1 u $ should be a solution to the original equation, but it somehow isn't." No wonder, since it is $x=\frac2t+\frac1u$ which should be a solution of $x'=\ldots$, not $\frac1u$.

Comment: Yeah I messed this type with linear equation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Given a particular solution, you can use the reduction of order technique and assume a solution of the type $x(t)=v(t)\gamma(t)=2v(t)/t$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{2v'(t)}{t} &- \frac{2v(t)}{t^2} = - \frac{4}{t^2} -\frac{2v(t)}{t^2} + \frac{4v^2(t)}{t^2} \Rightarrow \frac{tv'(t)}{2} = v^2(t) - 1 \\
&\Rightarrow \int \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{1-v^2} = \tanh^{-1} v = -\int \frac{2\mathrm{d}t}{t} = -2\log t + C \\
&\Rightarrow v(t) = -\tanh(2\log t + C) \Rightarrow \boxed{x(t) = -\frac{2\tanh(2\log t + C)}{t}.}
\end{aligned}
$$